# jQuery UI buttonset colour doesn't clear out after de-selecting

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, button

I'm sure I'm not the only person asking this question. When you have a jQuery UI implementation, and you use the `.buttonset();` command to turn a set of checkboxes into a button-set (multi selectable), I'm having trouble when a user de-selects an item after selecting it.

So let's say on hover, it turns into a certain colour (based on the settings of the jQueryUI theme I downloaded), and after clicking, it turns into the active state colour. When I click the same item again, and move the mouse away, it remains the hover colour, causing confusion as to whether the item is deselected or not.

And this only happens on Firefox only - seems to work fine on Chrome & Safari.

Here's a demo link: http://www.tylervolker.com/mls-search

I tried to force a blur() event to these items but no dice it seems.

```
$('.label').click(function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
```

What am I missing? Or is this just a Firefox thing I need to live with until either jQueryUI updates their code, or Firefox appends this?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be this known jQuery UI bug - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5518.  The button widget [isn't set to be addressed by the jQuery UI dev team until 1.11](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138038/Roadmap) so I wouldn't expect a fix for this anytime soon.

There are some suggested workarounds in the related issues on that ticket.